# haskell: binary calculator recursion and return values?

Tags: haskell, recursion, binary, calculator

I wanted to change decimal numbers into binary numbers per recursion and if else!

```
binary2 x =
   if x > 0
       then binary x
       else 999

binary x =
    if x `mod` 2 > 0
      then 1 && binary2 (x/2)
      else 0 && binary2 (x/2)
```

well returning `0` or `1` in combination with boolean does not work, I want to return whether `0` or `1` and then referate again to the function but with half the value as before until `x < 1`! Therefore `x/2`...

Comment: What are you imagining the types of these functions to be?  Are you wanting to turn an `Int` into its binary representation as a `String`?  An `Int` is an `Int` to a computer regardless of what base you are concerned with.  Decimal, binary, etc are just ways of representing a number as a sequence of characters, it's not how a computer actually stores the number.

Comment: yeah actually thats my question, for example '21' -> 10101 ... so I have to work with strings?

Comment: You will need to work with strings or some other ordered sequence type.  Since strings are just lists of `Char`s (literally `type String = [Char]`) that's the easiest to work with.

Comment: so i return a string, which means i need to put the result in the string...

Comment: to you want a full spoiler or just a hint? A possible hint would be to go and look at `quotRem`

Comment: also you probably want to use `++` or `:` instead of `&&` ;)

Comment: where is the difference, i thought i could link with && operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
binary2 :: Int -> [Int]
binary2 x
  | x > 0 = binary x
  | otherwise = []


binary :: Int -> [Int]
binary x
  | x `mod` 2 > 0 = binary2 (x `div` 2) ++ [1]
  | otherwise     = binary2 (x `div` 2) ++ [0]
```

So I'd just choose a list of Ints.

Comment: well how does those "|" work and "otherwise" ? and if i want to divide my variable i guess i have to chose x`div`2 over x/2 right?

Comment: Those are guards, please have a look here for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures

Comment: The `|` and `otherwise` are showing how to use [guards](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards), which basically turn into big if-then-else statements.  So it'd be equivalent to ```if x > 0 then binary x else []``` and ```if x `mod` 2 > 0 = binary2 .. ++ [1] else binary2 ... [0]```.

Comment: The difference between `div` and `(/)` is that the former is for Integral and the latter for Fractional.

Comment: alright, but one benefit might be i can skip "if then else" with those guards right?

Comment: Yes, if-then-else is not very haskell and only preferred in e.g. anonymous functions or something where guards don't fit very well.

Answer (score 0):

binary, decimal, hexadecimal etc. are representation systems for numbers. They only matter when you deal with strings containing numbers, not when you deal with numbers on the programming language level.